# Not saving into file

Tags: java, file, file-io, client-server, printwriter

In my client-server program the client inputs some string that is suppossed to be saved into a text file (in the server directory). I have a separate method for saving into file.
The client inputs and send the information (into the server) in the following format:
*PersonDetalis(Name,ID,Phone Number)*

But it is not creating any file, nor saving anything there.

This is the portion of Server side code that is responsible for saving into file:

```
 private static void saveIntoFile(String name, String id, String phnNum) {
    try {
        String custName = name.substring(name.indexOf('(') + 1, name.length());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("CustomerDetails" + name + "_" + phnNum + ".txt");
        String fileInfo = "Customer name: " + custName + "\n ID: " + id + "\n Phone Number: " + phnNum;

        out.println(fileInfo);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error saving file.");
    }
}
```

And calling the method this way:

```
 saveIntoFile(param[0], param[1], param[2]);
```

Comment: out of curiosity, can you test the method by itself and make sure it actually creates the file and writes to it?

Comment: Is there any exceptions in the log file? Also are you sure you have the right default server directory?

Comment: brso05, no there is no exception, and yes its the right server directory.

Comment: This code works fine for me! Are you sure the file isn't there and that you're looking at the right place for it?

Comment: add this line into several places into ur method and see if it prints: `System.out.println("here");`

Comment: it is working, finally.